# In python, I know that the operator *= calls the method __imul__(). What combination do I use to call the _mul_ method?

Tags: python, list, operators

Absolute newbie to programming and to python. I am still going through my first set of tutorials and merely just learning about in-place assignment operators, so newer than new.  I am using python 3.8.

I know that the operator *= calls the **imul** method to change/update the assigned value of the named variable in-place during an iterative operation.  What character combination do I use to call the *mul* method so the script does not change the original assigned value of the variable but I can use the temporary resulting value as an object for an intermediate result that will not be reused later? Or is the *mul* operation never actually used and that is why I can not find a keystroke combination for it?

I don't have an example I need help with.  This is purely theoretical as I try to educate myself with syntax.  Just wondering how to invoke the non-in-place versions of these operators as I have only seen reference to the standard in-place operators like +=, -=, *=, @=, /=, //=, %=, etc.

Sorry if this is too basic a topic for this forum.  If these sorts of simple newbie questions are inappropriate here, can you suggest a more appropriate forum for me to go to until I become accomplished?  I am sure I will have more questions along these lines and do not want to intrude on the community.

Comment: just `*` ?......

Answer (score 0):

It's just `*`, see:

```
class SomeClass:
    origin = 10

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.origin * other

cls = SomeClass()
print(cls * 10)
# 100
```

Comment: I was hoping to use this in an iterative indexing situation to decrement an assigned starting value "Item_price" by "discount" depending on customer tenure and number of orders  to generate and return a customized "item_price" every time the operation is called and for as many iterations as needed without permanently changing the value of "item_price" so that base "item_price" resets for the next customer. I did not want to change the value of "item_price" beyond the use for each customer but want decrement to calculate off the initial value as long as the loop stayed on that same customer.